# How to change the output of a multiple image field for a node?

Tags: nodes

I have a content type (called **Gallery**)  with a image field  (called **field_gallery**) which allows to upload and show 10 images.

Now I create a node and upload the images. The output shows those images wrapped with a div tag. Like:

```
<div class="field-item even"> <img …. /> </div>
<div class="field-item odd"> <img …. /> </div>
<div class="field-item even"> <img …. /> </div>
```

Instead of this I need it to be something like:

```
<img class="field-item even"  …. /> 
<img class="field-item odd"  …. /> 
<img class="field-item even"  …. />
```

How can I accomplish this. Should I use an alter function? How?
thanks

Comment: Probably you want to implement some carousel or slider? Have you check if it works in this formate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You can overwrite the field output template, e.g. field--field-name.tpl.php, or a module template, if that's the case. See http://drupal.org/node/1089656.
2. You can overwrite the node template for this content type (node--type.tpl.php). Type in `<pre><?php print_r($node); ?></pre>` to find the element you want. For template information, see http://drupal.org/node/1089656.
3. You can create a page in Views.